# Rails render template messes up I18n scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, format, render, rails-i18n

The controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end
end
```

When controller responds show action as JS, `show.js.erb` contains the following:

`$('#main-content').html('<%= j( render( template: "profiles/show.html.erb" ) ) %>');`

The problem is that I18n.t's scope get messed up when it attempts to fetch keys:
`ActionView::Template::Error (translation missing: en.profiles.show.html.erb.followers)`.

If I don't specify `.html.erb` part, it attempts to render `show.js.erb` which happens a infinite loop, so I must supply the html format.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the main part of profiles/show.html.erb into a partial:

profiles/_show.html.erb

then render as:

```
$('#main-content').html('<%= j raw render "profiles/show" %>')
```

You can also render your profiles/show.html.erb the same way

```
<%= render 'show' %> <%# renders the partial %>
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! In fact I believe it doesn't make sense to render a template inside a view, which is show.js.erb. Partial makes more sense and it is working now.